# Cannot start tomcat7 on ubuntu 16.04 - job for tomcat7.service failed

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to run tomcat7 on ubuntu 16.04 but when I execute

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```

I get

> Job for tomcat7.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat7.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

when I run `systemctl status tomcat7.service` I get

> tomcat7.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat7; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-21 22:21:52 UTC; 6min ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
>     Process: 3755 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb sudo[3763]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano /etc/default/tomcat7
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb sudo[3763]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb tomcat7[3755]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb sudo[3763]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> Apr 21 22:21:52 mitutorweb systemd[1]: tomcat7.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

I have found other similar questions but the reasons are different. In my case I got `Error opening terminal: unknown`

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I got the same error, and instead of "service tomcat7 start" command, I tried "bash  /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh", my website is up again but I wonder why the first one didn't work

Comment: @patti_jane I'm facing exactly the same, and what's happening is the almost identical to what you mentioned except that for me it is tomcat8. Did you fix it? If yes, could you please the solution? Thanks.